# Objective-C proxy for protocol Xcode compiler warnings

Tags: objective-c

I have a class which acts as a generic proxy for forwarding delegates. By implementing `respondsToSelector` and `forwardInvocation` I am able to use this class to forward selectors that would be sent to a delegate for various UI controls.

The problem is that when I use this class I get a compiler warning. For example, if I use it to forward messages to the UITableViewDelegate:

```
DelegateForwarder* _forward = [[DelegateForwarder alloc] init];
_tableView.delegate = _forward;
```

I get the compiler warning:

```
Assigning to id<UITableViewDelegate> from incompatible type 'DelegateForwarder'
```

I know that the warning is generated because DelegateForwarder does not adopt the `UITableViewDelegate` delegate, but I do not want it to - because the forwarding mechanism it provides is entirely generic.

Despite the warning my code runs as intended.

Is there anything I can do to indicate in some way to the compiler and users of this class that it uses message forwarding, so the fact that it does not adopt a specific protocol is not an issue?

Comment: Not entirely sure of myself here but does `id _forward = [[DelegateForwarder alloc] init];` remove the warnings?

Comment: @PhillipMills you're a genius - yes it does :-) - if you could expand on why this works as an answer to the question, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comments....

Since `id` is called a "generic object type", it's use is a signal to the type-checking mechanism that the nature of the referenced object is to be considered completely dynamic.  This means that code such as...

```
DelegateForwarder* _forward = [[DelegateForwarder alloc] init];
_tableView.delegate = _forward;
```

...implies that the `DelegateForwarder` variable should be checked for conformance, whereas...

```
id _forward = [[DelegateForwarder alloc] init];
_tableView.delegate = _forward;
```

...is a "trust me" type of declaration.

Comment: Thanks - a concise and clear explanation. Moving from C# to Objective-C is not without its difficulties!

Comment: Just to add, -init methods typically return id, so `_tableView.delegate = [[DelegateForwarder alloc] init]` is also an option.

Comment: and casting does the job too: `_tableView.delegate = (id)_forward;`. These are all about suppressing the compiler type checking.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added `<UITableViewDelegate>` to a list of `DelegateForwarder`'s protocols. In general it's more proper way than initializing with generic "id" type.

Comment: Quoting from the original question: *"I know that the warning is generated because DelegateForwarder does not adopt the UITableViewDelegate delegate"*

Comment: Agrh. Didn't pay enough attention, sorry :)). Then, yes, either casting with (id) (i.e. _tableView.delegate = (id)_forward;) or initializing with id-type.